# What are the tools/systems used to automate the development of HTML5 websites?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3, automation

First up, before you SO mods think this is a lame-ass question by an idiot new developer looking for a quick and easy solution to what is a large and difficult problem space, I'm a dev with 15+ years of experience and I've worked with a range of languages and technologies. I understand HTML5 website development, and have already built 5+ websites using Bootstrap 3. I've built a couple of CMS systems and tools to automate my workflow and help generate such websites. My question is about the existing tools/systems that devs use, as I am unaware of any.

I know about SASS/LESS but I'm not aware of how it can automate my workflow. IMO it only allows usage of variables to help change constants easily; correct me if I'm wrong.

**What are the tools/systems available to automate the design/development of modern HTML5 websites? Specifically the design of CSS and quick development of HTML pages.**

Are all the Bootstrap-based HTML5 websites made by hand? I know there are "website builders" and other lame tools with drag-and-drop modules (CMS systems) but that's not what theme designers use when creating new templates, do they?

- For example [this theme](http://preview.themeforest.net/item/enhenyero-engineeringindustrial-theme/full_screen_preview/10816665?ref=jqueryrain&clickthrough_id&redirect_back=true) on the envato marketplace; Did the designers/developers of this slave away using hand editing tools (like Notepad++) to design the CSS and HTML?
- For example this [icon](https://livedemo00.template-help.com/wt_51405/images/page1_img2.png); As you can see its two-part (black on top and white below). This allows it to change color when you [rollover the button](https://livedemo00.template-help.com/wt_51405/). Was this icon created by hand in PS?

I'm asking if there are any professional systems available to design CSS in an automated fashion, or extract/reuse CSS definitions across projects, or automate in any way the HTML content creation.

I apologize for the long winded question but I could think of no shorter way to describe this.

Answer (score 0):

[Stylizer](http://www.skybound.ca/) is a tool that helps you modify CSS in a more efficient manner. Not exactly automation but perhaps it could help you.

[image: style tool]